# Compare years in Tableau when you have months on another axis

Tags: tableau-api, google-trends

I'm working with Google Trends data, and I'm trying to compare months year on year.

At the moment, I'm getting this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/64gku.png

But, I'd like to overlay the years so that I can compare month on month performance more visually.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkERC.png

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having YEAR(Week) on the columns shelf, drag it to color.